# Troubleshoot cause of document not ready in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

for some reason my script that has

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

is not being executed. Looks like at the point the script is executed, the page is being loaded. However, I don't know which script that causing it. Could anyone suggest how to troubleshoot this?

regards,
ethereal1m

More detail:

I have a Jssor code attached in the header and it gives me the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: c is undefined
```

I just realized it now that the error existed. I conclude that the page was still loading by stepping in using debugger and that part of the code, $(document).ready(function() {, got skipped, hence the conclusion. By showing my other part of my code is not relevant of this problem, since the problem is not a code that wrongly executed, rather a part that is not executed.

Go back to the error, could this be related to the problem? If yes, I would like a help from the jassor team please... If not, need other suggestion...

Last updated:

The problem is not in jssor, but in my code.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: *"Looks like at the point the script is executed, the page is being loaded"* - the page itself, or other resources like images..?

Comment: show more code... there is far from enough context for anyone to assist here. How do we know the code is even valid?

Comment: @ethereal1m instead of adding information in comments, [edit] your question and update it there...

Comment: Hi all, I edit my question with additional info. @tj, judging from what it seems looks like the page itself, not sure though...

Comment: @George, yes, they are tagged correctly and jQuery is loaded before them

Comment: the console is a magical invention, It prevents questions like this. sadly even the console can't stop some..

Comment: @ethereal1m can you share the full code, or an online demo such as jsfiddle..?

Comment: if it's a JQuery problem you would get something like "Error: '$' is undefined". if you think the code is executing before the document loads, just put an alert at the end of your html and one on the start of your code, see which fires first.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help guys, the problem loading of the page is caused by the error. Thanks for reminding me about the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your included scripts cause that

```
TypeError: c is undefined
```

and jQuery never gets executed. Exclude your scripts to see which one is causing that error.

Comment: Yes, this is the cause of the problem thanks